# Active Page Triangle Marker in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-shapes

I'm looking to create an active page marker like the one pictured. The title probably doesn't do a great job of describing what I'm trying to do here.

What I'm looking for is a border that has an curved triangle active page marker using CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using to `<div>` tags only.

Setting the width of both container wil set the triangle on different placeses.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.left {
  float: right;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple way to achieve the result using a single corner border radius on two small `divs` with a bottom border - to move the 'triangle', you only need to adjust the `left` position of the `container' element.  It's not perfect, as the border fades towards the tip of the pointer, but it may pass the aesthetics test:

```css
#line {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #888888;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 53px;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#left,
#right {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #888888;
  height: 50px;
}
#left {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 0;
}
#right {
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  The display in the sandbox seems to be inconsistent - here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ze4tyshv/)

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `before`, `after` & `border-radius` to achieve it.
See an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNqPpy